# Javascipt loaded file dynamically but could not access constructor. X is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, module

I'm trying to get rid off `import` statements but want to dynamically load Javascript files.

I'm using this class to do it.

```
export function JSImport<T>(
    importPromise: Promise<T>,
): Promise<T> {
    // CommonJS's `module.exports` is wrapped as `default` in ESModule.
    return importPromise.then((m: any) => (m.default || m) as T);
}
```

Anyway, when imported file has used to be with constructor parameters, I get error.

Here is the old usage (which works well):

```
declare let Tiff: any;
const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
```

Here is the new usage:

```
   const importTiff = JSImport(
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "Tiff" */ 'Tiff'),
    );



   try {
    importTiff.then((Tiff: any) => {
    const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
    ....
    }
```

In new codeline, I get error which says that TypeError: **Tiff is not a constructor**

Tiff variable looks like this in Chrome console.
[image]

How to use it as a constructor ?

Comment: Your whole problem is that you're wrapping the call and the type information doesn't flow the way you think it does. I don't understand why you have the wrapper in the first place. It's just pointless. `try { import(/* webpackChunkName: "Tiff" */ 'Tiff').then(({default: Tiff}) => { const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});`. If you're dead set on your factoring, just write `const importTiff = import(/* webpackChunkName: "Tiff" */ 'Tiff');` and that's fine too.

Comment: Also, TS and Webpack can handle the synthesis of a default export from CJS so I don't understand why you would write that logic

Comment: Well, when I use it in webpack, bundled file is getting bigger. For most users, this package will not be used. That's why we do not want to load bigger bundled files in the beginning of application. We converted most of the import file in this method and decrease the website openning time. However, this module needs constructor and I couldn't use it proparly.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

The webpack dynamic import `import(/* chunkNameHint */ "moduleName")` really gives a module, that you identify as generic `T` in your `JSImport` function:

```
export function JSImport<T>(
    importPromise: Promise<T>, // TypeScript infers T to be the output of the dynamic import, i.e. the full module
): Promise<T>
```

Instead of trying to automatically "unpack" the module (which may have a default and/or named exports), you can direclty use the dynamic import:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "Tiff" */ 'Tiff')
  .then((module) => module.default) // Assuming the module has a default export and it is the one you need
  .then((Tiff: any) => {
    const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
    // ....
   });
```